# How to configure the Angular 2 environment setting by angular-cli?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to use angular-cli to configure the environment setting from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#build-targets-and-environment-files

But after I run "ng build --prod -aot", the output pages still show the content from original environment/environment.ts. I expect this file will be overwritten by environment/environment.prod.ts, but it looks like not.

My folder structure is like:

> - angular-cli.json
> - ...
> - src/
>
>   - app/
>
>     - ...
>   - environment/
>
>     - environment.dev.ts
>     - environment.prod.ts
>     - environment.ts
>   - main.ts
>   - ...

My angular-cli.json:

```
"apps": [
{
  "root": "src",
  ...,
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
  ...
```

In my main.ts file, I import the "environment":

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

And here is my ng version:

> angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1 
>   node: 6.9.1 
>   os: win32 x64

Does any one know what's wrong with me? Really thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the source element in your environments array:

```
"source": "environments/environment.ts",
```